# Applying SLD to vector layer in OpenLayers 2?

Tags: qgis, openlayers-2, geoserver, vector, sld

I'm trying to apply an SLD style to a vector layer in OpenLayers. I already took a look on google and here and I got a lot of information, but still I don't manage to achieve the result I'm looking for. Here is the code:

```
var map;

function init() {

    OpenLayers.ProxyHost = 'proxy.php?url=';

    map = new OpenLayers.Map("map", {});
    var park = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS('Park',
                       'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/PK/wms',
                       {
                           layers: 'PK:park'
                       },
                       {
                           isBaseLayer: true,
                       });

    map.addLayers([park]);


    var roads = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector('Roads', {
        protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
            url: 'roads.xml',
            format: new OpenLayers.Format.GML({
                extractAttributes: true
            })
        }),
        strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()]
    });

    map.addLayers([roads]);


    //SLD
    var format = new OpenLayers.Format.SLD();
    OpenLayers.Request.GET({
        url: 'style/roadsStyle.xml',
        success: function (req) {
            sld = format.read(req.responseXML || req.responseText);
            styles = sld.namedLayers.interpreted.userStyles;
            roads.styleMap.styles.default = styles;
        }
    });

    LayerSwitcher = new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher();
    MousePosition = new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition();
    PanZoomBar = new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar();
    map.addControls([LayerSwitcher, MousePosition, PanZoomBar]);


    if (!map.getCenter()) {
        map.zoomToMaxExtent()
    };

};
```

Pretty simple one, but, with this, the console returns error and the style is not applied and I don't know what I did wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Found what was the problem. Following that example, I thought that that syntax was referring to properties inside OpenLayers. Instead it wasn't. Where you have to indicate the style, you have to put the name of the namedLayer of your sld, like so:

```
var format = new OpenLayers.Format.SLD();
    OpenLayers.Request.GET({
        url: 'style/roadsStyle.xml',
        success: function (req) {
            sld = format.read(req.responseXML || req.responseText);
            styles = sld.namedLayers.NAMEOFYOURNAMEDLAYER.userStyles[0];
            roads.styleMap.styles.default = styles;
        }
    });
```